# Selecting a DGV Cell

Tags: c#, winforms

Please, what is wrong here

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in frm02.dgv02.Rows)
{
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
if (cell.Value.ToString() == "323")
//if (cell.RowIndex == 3)
{
cell.Selected = true;
```

I got NullReferenceException

If I replace first **if** with the second one - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in a cell that you are accessing seems to contain a null value.  You are then calling .ToString() on that null value.  You could do a null check before you try to call .ToString() on that value.

You would do that with:

```
if (cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString() == "323")
```

Comment: You're welcome.  As a rule, it's generally good practise to check for null values before trying to read or perform an operation on a value that could potentially be a null value.

Comment: but, what is then the purpose of "if" statement. "if" should mean "if". If a cell is null that means "if" is not satisfied, i.e. = false. So, no cell should be selected.

Comment: 'if (booleanCheck) {
    executingCode;
}'  The "booleanCheck" ALWAYS has to be performed to determine IF the "executingCode" should run.  The "if" only determines if the inside will execute.  You were originally getting the NullReferenceException on the "booleanCheck".

Comment: You were calling the .ToString() method on cell.Value.  .ToString() does not work on a null value, hence the exception.  If there is an error within an if condition, then an exception will generally still be thrown.

Comment: if a cell is empty then cell.Value.ToString is not '323'. So - false. But never mind. Thankyou once more.

Comment: The cell was not empty.  The cell contained a null value. That is also not '323', you are correct.  But, you cannot call ToString on a null value.  Effectively you were doing if Null.ToString() == '323'.  You cannot perform .ToString() on Null values.

Comment: I see that I can't call ToString() on a nullValue, but... I should can do that. null.ToString should be null, so not 323 or any. But this is source code syntax matter.